# How do I fake a sms system notification?

Tags: android

Hello everyone I have a question...
I'm trying to make my sms faker app, and I can insert the fake sms into the inbox but I cant trigger the notification about the new sms...
anyone know how can I trigger it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is intended as a place to present code that you have researched, written, and attempted to debug. Useful questions have relevant code samples and detailed error messages. You only seem to ask: "How do I do it?"

Comment: @Sam - That's a bit narrow-minded, since not everything related to coding is code. This kind of question is fine under the http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: @derekerdmann Perhaps my tone sounds harsh. I _do not_ wish to discourage Theter's participation. Though to quote the FAQ, "the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of **source code** in them" and a community wiki: [Not Your Personal Research Assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128548#128553). If Theter adds a sample of how or why these popular search engine results don't work: [Android sms notification problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4870069/1267661) and [Phil's link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), **I will happily dive in & help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

when you read this, it is very easy